# read: Connection reset by peer while doing sshfs?

Tags: ssh, sshfs

I have a working directory "os" in my local machine which I want to mount to my raspberry pi. I am able to ssh into my pi and when I run this command from pi:

> > sshfs andy@192.168.1.92:/home/andy/os /root/andy/os/

I get the error:

> > read: Connection reset by peer

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no server installed to listen to in my machine, So I installed the openssh-server in my local machine which solved the problem:

> > sudo apt-get install openssh-server